# Paging 3, Guava/LiveData: liveData onChanged gets called before data is fetched from server

Tags: java, android-livedata, android-paging-3, android-guava

I'm developing an android app for showing a list of products stored in a server. I'm using **Paging 3** lib with **Guava/LiveData**. When debugging, i found that the **method onChanged from LiveData is always called before the PagingSource fetch data from server and never more**.

**My PagingSource class**:

```
public class ProductsPagingSource extends ListenableFuturePagingSource<Integer, Product> {

    ProductsRepository productsRepository;

    Integer initialLoadSize = 0;

    public ProductsPagingSource(ProductsRepository productsRepository) {
        this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Integer getRefreshKey(@NonNull PagingState<Integer, Product> pagingState) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<LoadResult<Integer, Product>> loadFuture(@NonNull LoadParams<Integer> loadParams) {
        Integer nextPageNumber = loadParams.getKey();
        if (nextPageNumber == null) {
            nextPageNumber = 1;
            initialLoadSize = loadParams.getLoadSize();
        }

        Integer offSet = 0;
        if(nextPageNumber == 2) {
            offSet = initialLoadSize;
        }
        else {
            offSet = ((nextPageNumber - 1) * loadParams.getLoadSize()) + (initialLoadSize - loadParams.getLoadSize());
        }

        ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        Integer finalOffSet = offSet;
        Integer finalNextPageNumber = nextPageNumber;
        ListenableFuture<LoadResult<Integer, Product>> lf = service.submit(new Callable<LoadResult<Integer, Product>>() {
            @Override
            public LoadResult<Integer, Product> call() {
                List<Product> productsList = null;
                productsList = productsRepository.loadProducts(loadParams.getLoadSize(), finalOffSet);
                Integer nextKey = null;
                if(productsList.size() >= loadParams.getLoadSize()) {
                    nextKey = finalNextPageNumber + 1;
                }
                return new LoadResult.Page<Integer, Product>(productsList,
                        null,
                        nextKey);
            }
        });

        return lf;
    }
}
```

**The ViewModel class**:

```
public class HomeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    LiveData<PagingData<Product>> productsLd;

    public HomeViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        ProductsRepository productsRepository = new ProductsRepository(getApplication());
        CoroutineScope viewModelScope = ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(this);
        Pager<Integer, Product> pager = new Pager(new PagingConfig(10), () -> new ProductsPagingSource(productsRepository));
        productsLd = PagingLiveData.cachedIn(PagingLiveData.getLiveData(pager), viewModelScope);
    }

    public LiveData<PagingData<Product>> getProductsLd() {
        return productsLd;
    }

}
```

**Then, on method onCreate from HomeActivity, LiveData is observed**:

```
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, new ProductComparator());
        
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        LiveData<PagingData<Product>> productsLd = homeViewModel.getProductsLd();
        productsLd.observe(this, new Observer<PagingData<Product>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(PagingData<Product> productPagingData) {
                myAdapter.submitData(getLifecycle(),productPagingData);
            }
        });
```

**onChanged** is immediately called after the LiveData is obtained from ViewModel and before **loadFuture** from **ProductsPagingSource** is called, so the **PagingData** delivered is empty. Method **loadFuture** from **ProductsPagingSource** is called and the data is fetched correctly from server, but LiveData never triggers onChanged.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem. It was a silly error: i forgot to set the Adapter in the RecycleView.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).